# We are individually striving for wealth to be independent from necessity to work. Why society as whole is unwilling to be independent from work? AI

Tags: communism, socialism, technology, transhumanism

My question is arising from recent ChatGTP & plugins developments which provides the great tools for automation of jobs.

I can observe that people individually are striving to gain wealth and the most important thing of wealth is being independent from necessity to work. I am not saying that people are unwilling to work or that they will be unwilling to work in the future. No, of course not. Any human being needs self-realization and activities and they are doing and they will be doing this self-realization even in case if there is no pressure to work. I am just saying that people would are more happier and would be more happier if they have resources and independence to chose their activities (and work can be part of them). That is at individual level.

My question is about collective level - if people are striving to gain resources for being independent for work - why the people are unwilling to create political movements that leads to this goal - providing people with resources and independence from necessity to work?

Up to now the answer to my question was obvious. If the government wants to give resources to some (or all people) then this same government should grab those resources from the fruits of work of other people.

But that becomes more and more outdated situation. Today bit part of redistributable resources can be gained from the fruits of robot work and AI work. So, with every day such redistribution becomes possible without redistributing the gains of work of other human beings.

There can be political movement that greatly boost this process, e.g. by making AI, robotics, science education more accessible, more affordable, that empowers people to innovate, to experiment and create more and more robots, AI plugins, tools, systems. That moves the money from e.g. real estate operations to the boosting of science and technologies. Actually - China is doing exactly that with enormous R&D investments that are comparable to US R&D investments and even may surpass them in the near future, not to mention EU R&D investments that have some problems. But China also has no this explicit goal of luxury post-scarcity society without necessity to work.

So - my question is - **if people are individually striving for resources and work-independent life, then why people are not engaging in the political movements that specifically enables the technologies that can collectively enable post-scarcity society with work-independence?** It maybe quite possible that targeted and focused application or resources can result in such society. The climate change policies are similar in nature and implementation but they are not aiming at satisfaction of the single most important individual goal - resourcefullness and work-independence.

I am aware of Transhumanist parties in US, France, UK, Germany and some other countries, but they are incredibly small compared to the ongoing AI developments.

**Information added**. There is widespread notion in the Western societies, that the market forces will determine and lead the fate of automation. But digitalisation shows s.c. **job polarisation effect**, e.g. https://www.sciencespo.fr/research/cogito/home/the-political-consequences-of-technological-change/?lang=en and BBC article on ChatGPT job losses https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-65102150 also mentions, that middle income jobs will be impacted most likely.

**If we apply the free market logic, then middle income people will be pushed into physical, low wage, mundane jobs** and market forces will preserve such situation for longer period of time, because people will be pressed to accept such low wage jobs and robotics companies will have little incentive to automate them.

This is clearly visible even today. Robotics companies develop surgery systems such as Da Vinci and social robots such as Ameca robots and military robots such as Boston Dynamics, but slaughterhouse and meat/fish processing automation (which requires less precision) is less attractive to these companies.

It is OK, if people consciously accept such downward moving trend, at least for some time. But maybe this is the theme, where some intervention is needed? Some active robotics development policy for automation of low wage jobs, automation of those processes that are neglected by robotics companies?

And regarding the automation of physical work. Tesla Optimist robot project shows that the **cognitive skills are the most challenging part of the humanoid robot building and GPT can address those skills effectively**. And Google this year multimodal large model (extension of ChatGPT like models of visual, motion/robotics skills data) https://ai.googleblog.com/2023/03/palm-e-embodied-multimodal-language.html is one step in this direction. So - the physical robotics will soon can experience ChatGPT-like breakthrough.

**Clarification added that tries to address the possible reason of downvotes and closevotes.** **The possible reason of close/downvotes could be argument that there are ready technologies. But the comparison with greening and recycling economy is very fit.** We have to develop many, many technologies for the greening of economy - including all the battery technologies and EVs (and EU comapnies are pretty conservative regarding this) and charging grid, we should develop all the stack of hydrogen technologies - engines, refilling networks, generation plants, we should improve solar cells, develop small nuclear reactors, develop fusion reactors and maybe even develop geoengineering solutions (like solar radiation shields or iron powders for oceans). All these tings for the greening are quite new and almost everything is introduced by governmental force (either by regulation or by subsidies) not the market forces. So - we are able to find resources and to make innovation in the greening sphere.

Then why we are so sceptical about innovation in the work-dependence sphere? **Both things - greening and post-scarcity - are needed for the people to be happy. Why there are political movements that are pushing greening and why there are no political movements that are pushing post-scarcity and independence fro work - that is the reformulation and clarification of my question.**

Comment: There may be temptation to require surveys, data, that people are really unwilling to support such political movement. But, IMHO, the facts are abundant, that people are unwilling. E.g. there are no popular political parties with such agenda. Media reports about ChatGPT stresses that new jobs will be created, that there will be winners and losers and that nothing could be done about this. EU had Future of EU popular forum and the outcome didn't asked for such scenario. UBI income referendum in EU gained only some 30% of votes from the necessary 1M signatures to go ahead, etc., etc.

Comment: So, please, be kind and not ask for other datasets about unwillingness of people. I may even predict the behavior of many SE users that will express such unwillingness themselves.

Comment: Regarding my assumption, that jobs can be automated, there is OpenAI report about impact of current GPT version https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.10130 (of course, there will be future GPT versionas as well) and here is Microsoft reserach report about sparks of AGI in current GPT version https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.12712 AGI stands for Artificial General Intelligence and for years such bold aim was outside to scope of mainstream science and businesses. Now, AGI is the target which science and business are striving to achieve. So - maybe politicians and society should commit to this goal as well?

Comment: the simple answer: a classic deadweight loss caused by poor coordination between actors. Why don't actors coordinate? because getting 150 million people (about the number it would take to make the decision, the rest are forced into agreement by violence as they already are today) to reach a global optimum is really hard, whereas it's easy for each one person to strive for their local optimum

Comment: Aside from the problem that you just felt you had to steer the answers a certain way by expanding at length on the question:  chatgpt is an unreliable system currently.  That means it is not guaranteed to be correct on questions with absolute, objective, solutions.  Second, ask yourself, in the last week of purchasing goods and services in real life, how many of those jobs can chatgpt do (plumber, waiter, restaurant cook, etc...)?  Third, if we had a perfect chatgpt with all the physical robots needed for it, what's in it for the poor Morlocks maintaining the robots while the Elois cavort?

Answer (score 10):

> why people are not engaging in the political movements that specifically enables the technologies that can collectively enable post-scarcity society with work-independence?

The technologies are not disabled to have any need to politically enable them. They're just not entirely there yet.

Right now, ChatGPT cannot replace builders, road workers, farmers etc. Physical robots in enough quantities need to be invested in, manufactured, tested and  deployed. Still several years to get there.

So, there doesn't appear to be much (if any) political or legal impediment to that to push through. Not yet at least. It just needs to be done, and it takes time and money.

Comment: Robot builder https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wrQLDoJ6cw and construction worker https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMLPhk6b0gA Hands free farm https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jM9bbrhKbOc Road building robots https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzxnmd6b-b0 that though involves some human driven machines, but which are being automated by robotic driving systems https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oqEKyseu2U

Comment: Vertical farming by robots https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXuQKoQCtOc

Comment: I added additional information in my question that addresses your inquiries that are most likely shared by others too.

Comment: @TomR I don't say they do not exist, I say they are not massively available on end user market. I live in rural New Zealand famous for its farming and I have not yet seen ANY robots in here. Same with seasonal kiwifruit picker workers. To get it all robotized we just need investments and time, not political movements.

Comment: Note that the more likely option isn't "*AI-driven robots* working in construction", it's "*telematically-driven robots being operated by a dude in a shed in Chennai on $3 a day* in construction"

Comment: Presuming, that those made redundant by AI, will have enough resources to move to higher paying jobs. If there are no resources for upskilling, then AI-redundancy will lead (and is already leading) to downward movement. See my references from French research. I.e. it may be possible that US dudes will be happy for $3 pay as well.

Comment: I do believe most workers are not from these categories and in fact our economy is incentivizing work in the fields that mostly produce bullshit and *could* be replaced by ChatGPT. So it's irrelevant that certain fields cannot be replaced by ChatGPT.

Comment: @user253751 The cost of living is driven by the necessity to get exactly that kind of work done — to produce real food and infrastructure for living. You can't be fed and kept warm/dry by some bullshit.

Comment: @Greendrake tell me how working in an office to write software that does [redacted] that they can already do with our competitor's software or 5 minutes in Excel is helping *anyone* get fed or infrastructured. Farmers are certainly not suffering from a lack of Excel charts, nor are infrastructure projects. They exist primarily to trick investors into giving more money to projects, i.e. to circumvent an ENTIRELY ARTIFICIAL roadblock which stands in the way of feeding and infrastructuring.

Comment: @Greendrake Our society would be better off if nobody had the ability to make even more bullshit Excel charts on demand, then investors wouldn't be able to demand them and we'd spend that effort working on **actual feeding and infrastructure** or at least on automation of the same.

Answer (score 9):

There are several moving pieces in this question. I want to list them out first.

1. Individuals accrue wealth to cover basic necessities in life. True.
2. AI revolution would increase worker productivity, which in turn increases the chance of overall wealth flowing in society. Probably true.
3. A more equal distribution of wealth - by means of taxation - is more likely to cover everyone's basic necessities, which in turn frees them to pursue more self-actualization. Probably true (see [Nordic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_model)).

There are, however, other considerations.

- The AI automation is still at its infancy, and while we can infer their potential economic benefit based on what they can do now, it would still take some time for them to be widely implemented in commercial setting. In short, we still don't actually know how much more productivity they can generate, let along how much more wealth they can produce.
- If AI successfully generates more wealth in society, it may not automatically mean society would embrace more equal distribution of wealth. In the most ideal scenario, we would all be like Finland and create a strong social safety net for all. But it is equally likely that - if a country already has entrentched unequal distribution mechanism like the United States - the abundance of wealth would just be distributed in the same direction as it was before the AI revolution. To put it in the American context, having more productive AI worker may not mean employers would make people work less and earn more, but that people should work even harder because the ceiling for potential profit has risen.
- If a society with high wealth inequality commits to transition to a more equal society after the AI revolution, there is still the question of how do you execute a "just transition". It's easy to say everyone should just quit their job and embrace the social safety net, but in practice it is probably not going to be that smooth. If you are a single mother working three minimum wage jobs, and someone tells you that you should quit because AI revolution has arrived, would you do it? How long would it take for the social safety net to actually arrive? Would it be good enough to meet your needs? Maybe it is safer to stay with the devil you know then to plunge into the unknown of economic pracarity. How do you ensure that no one gets left behind in the transition?

In short, whether AI can increase overall wealth in society is an **economic and technical question**, whereas whether a total increase in societal wealth would be distributed equally is a **political question**. The two are correlated, but they do not share inherent causality.